# Firefox on Windows: How to make the text cursor indicate text direction?

Tags: firefox, windows-10, right-to-left, text-cursor

When typing text in Windows and switching between left-to-right and right-to-left input languages, you typically get a visual indication on the text cursor to show you which mode you're in (LTR or RTL), like so:

[image: Text cursor indicates RTL language]

However, on Windows 10 when using Firefox, I've found that the indication is missing from the cursor:

[image: Text cursor not indicating RTL or LTR]

This is seen both in text boxes that make up the Firefox UI and in text boxes that are part of the web page contents.

How can I make the visual indication for LTR/RTL appear in Firefox on Windows 10?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a mis-feature of Mozilla's implemention of cursors in widgets. This is also very annoying when composing mail messages in Thunderbird - for years and on multiple platforms (Win XP, Win 7, Linux w/GTK).